# SimpleInjector and SDammann WebAPI versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I try to configer the SimpleInjector container to use it with the SDammann WebAPI Versioning

I have this in my WebAPI config..

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public sealed class AcceptHeaderRequestVersionDetector : SDammann.WebApi.Versioning.Request.AcceptHeaderRequestVersionDetector 
    {
        protected override ApiVersion GetVersionFromSingleHeader(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue headerValue)
        {
            string rawVersion = headerValue.Parameters.First(x => x.Name == "version").Value;
            int version = Convert.ToInt32(rawVersion);

            return new SemVerApiVersion(
                new Version(version, 0)
            );
        }
    }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.Register<DefaultControllerIdentificationDetector>();
        container.Register<DefaultRequestControllerIdentificationDetector>();
        container.Register<HttpConfiguration>(() => config);

        config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        container.Verify();

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new VersionedApiControllerSelector(config));

        ApiVersioning.Configure()
                     .ConfigureRequestVersionDetector<AcceptHeaderRequestVersionDetector>();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
     }
}
```

My controllers are available in the following folders....

[image]

When i just test the test controller everything works fine 
--> http:localhost/VDB.Service.WebAPI/Api/Test

Code below

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Version()
    {
        return "Version 1";
    }
}
```

When i try it with some other stuff like below then i get an error....
See picture below this code

```
public class OilTypesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRequestHandler<FindOilTypesQuery,FindOilTypesQueryResult>  _findOilTypesQueryHandler;
    private readonly IRequestHandler<CreateOilTypeCommand, CreateOilTypeCommandResult> _createOilTypeCommandHandler;

    public OilTypesController(FindOilTypesQueryHandler findOilTypesQueryHandler, CreateOilTypeCommandHandler createOilTypeCommandHandler)
    {
        _findOilTypesQueryHandler = findOilTypesQueryHandler;
        _createOilTypeCommandHandler = createOilTypeCommandHandler;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public CreateOilTypeCommandResult CreateOilType(CreateOilTypeCommand command)
    {
        var result = _createOilTypeCommandHandler.Execute(command);
        return result;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<OilTypeSummaryModel> GetOilTypes(ODataQueryOptions<OilType> oDataQuery)
    {
        var query = new FindOilTypesQuery(oDataQuery);
        return _findOilTypesQueryHandler.Execute(query).OilTypes.ToOilTypeSummaryModel();
    }
}
```

[image]

BTW my Global.asax looks like this...

```
 public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Container container = new Container();
        container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.Register<IVdbCommandContext, VdbCommandContext>(Lifestyle.Transient);
        container.Register<IVdbQueryContext, VdbQueryContext>(Lifestyle.Transient);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlerFilter());

        // Force code first migrations to check database and migrate if required
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<VdbCommandContext, Configuration>());

        VdbCommandContext vdbCommandContext = new VdbCommandContext();
        vdbCommandContext.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
}
```

It could be that this are some basic things. But i am new to Webdevelopment and that stuff.
In my daily job i am using BizTalk and that stuff. :)
But i want to learn new stuff. :)

### EDIT FROM THIS POINT

I now get the following error, but i don't know why...

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'OilTypesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": " at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\ \ at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\ \ at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
"InnerException": {
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "No registration for type OilTypesController could be found and an implicit registration could not be made. The constructor of type OilTypesController contains the parameter of type IRequestHandler<FindOilTypesQuery, FindOilTypesQueryResult> with name 'findOilTypesQueryHandler' that is not registered. Please ensure IRequestHandler<FindOilTypesQuery, FindOilTypesQueryResult> is registered in the container, or change the constructor of OilTypesController.",
"ExceptionType": "SimpleInjector.ActivationException",
"StackTrace": " at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()\ \ at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance(Type serviceType)\ \ at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)",
"InnerException": {
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "The constructor of type OilTypesController contains the parameter of type IRequestHandler<FindOilTypesQuery, FindOilTypesQueryResult> with name 'findOilTypesQueryHandler' that is not registered. Please ensure IRequestHandler<FindOilTypesQuery, FindOilTypesQueryResult> is registered in the container, or change the constructor of OilTypesController.",
"ExceptionType": "SimpleInjector.ActivationException",
"StackTrace": " at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultConstructorInjectionBehavior.BuildParameterExpression(ParameterInfo parameter)\ \ at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression(ParameterInfo parameter)\ \ at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(ConstructorInfo constructor)\ \ at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)\ \ at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation]()\ \ at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression(InstanceProducer producer)\ \ at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()\ \ at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\ \ --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\ \ at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildInstanceCreator()\ \ at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()"
}
}
}
```

My WebApi looks now likes this...
Controller is still the same...

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public sealed class AcceptHeaderRequestVersionDetector : SDammann.WebApi.Versioning.Request.AcceptHeaderRequestVersionDetector 
    {
        protected override ApiVersion GetVersionFromSingleHeader(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue headerValue)
        {
            string rawVersion = headerValue.Parameters.First(x => x.Name == "version").Value;
            int version = Convert.ToInt32(rawVersion);

            return new SemVerApiVersion(
                new Version(version, 0)
            );
        }
    }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.Register<DefaultControllerIdentificationDetector>();
        container.Register<DefaultRequestControllerIdentificationDetector>();
        container.Register(() => config);

        container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.Register<IVdbCommandContext, VdbCommandContext>();
        container.Register<IVdbQueryContext, VdbQueryContext>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlerFilter());

        config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        container.Verify();

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new VersionedApiControllerSelector(config));

        ApiVersioning.Configure()
                     .ConfigureRequestVersionDetector<AcceptHeaderRequestVersionDetector>();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
     }
}
```

**SECOND EDIT**

```
 public class FindOilTypesQueryHandler: IRequestHandler<FindOilTypesQuery,FindOilTypesQueryResult>
{
    private readonly IVdbQueryContext _vdbQueryContext;

    public FindOilTypesQueryHandler(IVdbQueryContext vdbQueryContext)
    {
        _vdbQueryContext = vdbQueryContext;
    }

    public FindOilTypesQueryResult Execute(FindOilTypesQuery request)
    {
        var oilTypes = request.ODataQuery.ApplyTo(_vdbQueryContext.OilTypes).Cast<OilType>();
        return new FindOilTypesQueryResult(oilTypes);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: MVC Application**
I get now something back when i do a test --> 'PostMan a chrome app'
Now i try to do that in an ASP.Net MVC application...

But i get the error...

```
    For the container to be able to create AccountController, it should contain exactly one public constructor, but it has 2.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: SimpleInjector.ActivationException: For the container to be able to create AccountController, it should contain exactly one public constructor, but it has 2.
Source Error: 


Line 27:             container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();
Line 28: 
Line 29:             container.Verify();
Line 30: 
Line 31:             DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

The accountController is the default accountcontroller...
My Global file looks like this in my MVC application.

Just like the guide on.... , no?https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mvcintegration.html

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            Container container = new Container();
            container.Register<IVdbService, VdbService>();
            container.Register<IRequestExecutor,RequestExecutor>();

            container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();

            container.Verify();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

}
    }

Comment: Please, don't add screenshots with stack traces to your question. Just paste the complete exception information (stack traces, exception messages, types, and inner exceptions) as text to your question.

Comment: Do call `container.RegisterWebApiControllers()` before calling verify. This makes your life way much easier, because this will allow Simple Injector to verify your controllers as well, which allows the application to blow up at the moment that `Verify` is called, instead of later on when the application is running.

Comment: @Steven I do that already since yesterday evening... After the edit on StackOverflow. I do that call before the "ExceptionHandlerFilter add", when i try just before the Verify i get an error like this "The container can't be changed after the first call to GetInstance, GetAllInstances and Verify."

Comment: To understand why you get that exception, please read [this part of the documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.7/decisions.html#container-is-locked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear:

> The constructor of type FindOilTypesQueryHandler contains the
>   parameter of type IVdbQueryContext with name 'vdbQueryContext' that is
>   not registered. Please ensure IVdbQueryContext is registered in the
>   container, or change the constructor of FindOilTypesQueryHandler.

This means that the `IVdbQueryContext` isn't registered. It is easy to see why, because you create two `Container` instances. The second one (in the `Application_Start` method) contains this `IVdbQueryContext` registration, but that instance is never used. The first one (in the `Register` method) is registered as `DependencyResolver` and therefore used by Web API for resolving your controllers, but this instance does not contain the `IVdbQueryContext` registration.

Best practice is to have [one single container instance per application](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html).

Comment: In https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html a link is present in the first Warning block which points to https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/349908 but alas, that link is not working anymore.

Comment: @Maarten: Thanks for reporting this. I'll fix this right away.

Comment: Is it better to add everything in the Globals.asax Or in the WebAPI register? But in the Global.asax i don't have the "HttpConfiguration"....

Comment: @Sven: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: @Steven I get some another error. Why should i add a parameterless constructor?

Comment: @Sven: You don't need a parameterless ctor. That's just Web API saying stupid things. Take a look at the inner exception. It says: "No registration for type OilTypesController could be found and an implicit registration could not be made. The constructor of type OilTypesController contains the parameter of type IRequestHandler<FindOilTypesQuery, FindOilTypesQueryResult> with name 'findOilTypesQueryHandler' that is not registered."

Comment: @Steven see in my edit question also for the   "container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());"  This should register the IRequestHandler, no?

Comment: @Sven: Your question is a bit unclear to me. `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` is Simple Injector's batch-registration facility. It will search for all non-generic implementations of this `IRequestHandler<T, R>` and will register them by their closed generic interface.

Comment: @Steven So it should register the IRequestHandlers for all my implementations. No? Like my "'findOilTypesQueryHandler" that he doesn't find...

Comment: @Sven: It registers all non-generic implementations of the `IRequestHandler<,>` interface and since you specify `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, it only looks in your Web API assembly. Are you sure that `findOilTypesQueryHandler` is defined in your Web API project? Are you sure that `findOilTypesQueryHandler` implements `IRequestHandler<,>`? Are you sure that `findOilTypesQueryHandler` does not depend on `IRequestHandler<,>` (because that would make it a decorator in it will be skipped if you do)?

Comment: @Steven I added my Handler in the first question... As you can see it implements the "IRequestHandler<,>", But it's in another assembly. How can i tell "SimpleInjector" to scan other assemblies...

Comment: @Sven: Just pass in the assembly you want to be scanned into the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric`. For instance: `container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());`

Comment: @Steven That works indeed. I get something back like described in the edited question... But when i try to call it with my MVC project i get a new error...

Comment: @Steven No problem anymore, i removed authentication for the moment... Don't need it for now... :)